# Google Sheets substitute carriage return

Tags: excel, google-sheets, find, substitution

How may I replace the carriage return (new line) in a cell with a comma and a space (", ") using the command SUBSTITUTE or any other suitable command.

As an example I want to change left cell to look like the right cell. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

char(10) is for newline, so:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,char(10),", ")
```

Answer (score 2):

Either, do it like Stefan said with `char(10)` or do the carriage return directly like:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1," <- hit Alt+Enter to make a new line inside a cell
",", ")
```

You also could simply copy/paste the "new line" (which i would do)... cus sometimes a `"new line" <> "new line"`
To do it in a clean way, i suggest this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(13)&CHAR(10),", "),CHAR(10),", ")
```

If you are not sure which kind of carriage return you are facing, it will be better to check for the "2-char-new-line" or you may stick with `CHAR(13)` which may cause trouble later :)